# Representability of smooth invertible Lipschitz functions by a finite composition of near-identity functions

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, approximation-theory

Theorem 1 of [this paper](http://phillong.info/publications/BEL18_identity.pdf) shows that

> For every positve integer $K$ and for every nonempty bounded domain $\mathcal X \subseteq \mathbb R^d$, the restriction on $\mathcal X$ of any function $h: \mathbb R^d \rightarrow \mathbb R^d$ satisfying:
>
> - **Invertibility:** $h$ is invertible.
> - **Lipschitz moothness:** There exists $L \in [0,\infty)$ such that $\|h'(x)u-h'(y)u\| \le L\|x-y\|\|u\|$, for all $x, u \in \mathbb R^d$.
> - **Positive orientation:** $\det(h'(x_0)) > 0$ for some $x_0 \in \mathcal X$.
> - **Lipschitz inverse:** $\|h^{-1}\|_{\text{Lip}} < \infty$,
>
> can be represented as a composition $h|_{\mathcal X} = h_1\circ h_2 \circ \ldots \circ h_K$ of near-identity functions, in the sense that
>   $$\||h_k - \operatorname{Id}_d\|_{\text{Lip}} = \mathcal O (\log(K)/K),\text{ for all }1 \le k \le K.
> $$

Unfortunately, the provided proof is very "manual".

## Question

- Is there a result from functional analysis, approximation theory, or a simple argument, which would automatically guarantee the **existence** of such an approximation in the above theorem or a similar statement ?

Comment: Two things: Is $\|\,\cdots\,\|_{\text{Lip}}$ the Lipschitz constant? You probably forgot to insert a link to some paper.

Comment: Yes $\|\cdot\|_{\text{Lip}}$ denotes the Lipschitz semi-norm. Also added omitted link to paper.